# Android: getText and setText not working on EditText with onKeyListener

Tags: android, android-edittext, gettext, settext

I'm working on an Android application and have a view with 3 EditTexts. What I'm trying to achieve is that on a numeric key being pressed in the last one should call the okKey event for that activity. The problem is that for the EditText on which I set the onKeyListener, neither getText nor setText methods work. Allow me to explain:

Suppose I initialize an empty string

```
String string1 = "";
```

In my onCreate method, I set the onKeyListener on one of the EditTexts

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    findViewById(R.id.EditText3).setOnKeyListener(this);
    ...
}
```

Now, if I write the following code in the overriding okKey method

```
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode >= KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0 && keyCode <= KeyEvent.KEYCODE_9) {
        string1 += ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText1)).getText();
        string1 += ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText2)).getText();
        string1 += ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText3)).getText();

        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText1)).setText("");
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText2)).setText("");
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText3)).setText("");
    }
return false;
}
```

Only EditText1 and EditText2 get cleared and the text in EditText3 does not get concatenated to string1. If I replace the condition of the If statement with

```
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
```

then on pressing Enter key (set as Next), it works as expected. I tried to add the setText("") in the onResume method of the activity too but with no difference in the result. I appreciate the time you took to read my question!

Edited: Added the "return false;" at the end of onKey method, I had it in my work but missed putting it in this question, was reminded by Chris's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Chris' answer, a check should be added to insure that event.getAction() is equal to KeyEvent.ACTION_UP; onKey gets called twice, and if getAction() is ACTION_DOWN (first time the method is called), the character won't yet have been added to the CharSequence returned by getText().

Answer (score 1):

When your setting the OnKeyListener your EditText3, your replacing what happens when you hit a key with that. Try `return false;` at the end of the onKey. This should pass the value to the proper location.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html

Returns

True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise.

Comment: I'm sorry I should have mentioned (or put in sample code) that I am returning false at the end of the onKey method.

Comment: @Mark, your suggestion is the answer, it solved the problem! Thanks man! Could you put your comment into an answer to the question so I can mark it as an answer?